# Are Conv nets suitable for Regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm training a CNN network to find coordinates of an object place on a 2d grid space. 
The problem is that the error is not going below 3 cm tolerance.
My data set consists of 1000 images (240x135 resolution).
I'm using a model with 7 conv-maxpool layers and then 5 dense layers (all relu activations).

**How can I reduce error further ??**

I have tried training for longer durations, used mini-batch GD, used l2 regularization, dropout..

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: It sounds like you have WAY too many parameters for only 1000 images. What is your parameter count?

Comment: Trainable parameters = 34237536, considering all weights of convnets and dense layers.